# Selecting last record by linq fails with "method not recognised"

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

i have following query to select the last record in the database

```
using (Entities ent = new Entities())
{
Loaction last = (from x in ent.Locations select x).Last();
Location add = new Location();
add.id = last.id+1;
//some more stuff
}
```

the following error is returned when calling the method containing these lines via "Direct event" on ext.net:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Prototype.DataAccess.Location Last[Location]
(System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Prototype.DataAccess.Location])' method,
and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

table structure is following:

```
int ident IDENTITY NOT NULL,
int id NOT NULL,
varchar(50) name NULL,
//some other varchar fields
```

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293639/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-last-really

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Last is not supported by Linq to Entities. Do `OrderByDescending` (usually by ID or some date column) and select first. Something like:

```
Location last = (from l in ent.Locations
                 orderby l.ID descending
                 select l).First();
```

Or

```
Location last = ent.Locations.OrderByDescending(l => l.ID).First();
```

See MSDN article [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx) for reference.