# MVC WebGrid of complex type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, webgrid

Im creating a webgrid. one of my column is of collection complex type:

```
[Table("RequestStatus",Schema="dbo")]
public class RequestStatus
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

and in my entity:

```
    public virtual ICollection<RequestStatus> RequestStatuses { get; set; }
```

in my webgrid i want to be able to sort by this property in a way similar to this:

```
   RequestStatuses.Last().Status
```

I created a readonly property in my entity:

```
    [NotMapped]
    public string LastRequestStatus
    {
        get { return this.RequestStatuses.Last().Status; }
    }
```

but i get:

System.NotSupportedException: The specified type member 'LastRequestStatus' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supporte

I assume that is becasue this property is not mapped to db field. is there a way to handle this situation out of the box or i need to write custom sorting for that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a some kind of custom sorting. 
when I issue in query string sort={propery which doesn't exist} webgrid doesnt do the sort but gives the result as is. 
if I edit the header of this column to issue a query string with the _LastRequestStatus (in my case), I check in controller if querystring["sort"] equals to this string (_LastRequestStatus) , do the appropriate sort (ASC,DESC - sortdir in querystring), and pass that list to the view as I did before. 
from there webgrid handles the paging as desired without intervention. All can be done in view+controller without the need for client-side script (which generally i have no problem with but i think this way it is more readable, especially if i see this code in a few months).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
get { return this.RequestStatuses.ToList().Last().Status; }
```

or

```
get { return this.RequestStatuses.OrderByDescending(ee=>ee.YourPropery).First().Status; }
```

And read this

[LINQ To Entities does not recognize the method Last. Really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293639/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-last-really)

Comment: that doesnt work. it won't work if i have a simple field which is not mapped to entity. for example: public string SomeProp { get; set;}. gives the same error.