# ASP.NET MVC Return the latest entry in table for the logged in user

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to get the latest record for the logged in employee in my `HolidayRequestForm`  table.

However based on advice from [LINQ To Entities does not recognize the method Last. Really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293639/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-last-really) I want to orderbydescending and select the first.

I've tried adding in orderbydescending but I get an error 
"Error  3   'System.Data.TypedTableBaseExtensions.OrderByDescending(System.Data.TypedTableBase, System.Func, System.Collections.Generic.IComparer)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context
"

Do I have it in the wrong place?

```
var SD = (from c in db.HolidayRequestForms.OrderByDescending
                        where (c.Employee.Email == name) && (c.Employee.EmployeeID == c.EmployeeID)
                        select c.StartDate);

        DateTime StartDate = SD.LastOrDefault();
```

I would like `StartDate` to give the latest result in the `HolidayRequestForm` table for the current logged in employee

Comment: OrderByDescending Is indeed a method, which requires a parameter to know what to order by - `OrderByDescending(f => f.PropertyToOrderDescendingBy)`

Comment: `Take(1)` is overkill if using `First` / `Last` @stuartd

Comment: @stuartd yep that was it thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.HolidayRequestForms.OrderByDescending
```

doesn't make sense for two reasons.

1. It is a method, which needs to be invoked (i.e. have `()` after it)
2. You need to tell it what to order **by**

I'd suggest this as a replacement:

```
var SD = (from c in db.HolidayRequestForms where (c.Employee.Email == name) && (c.Employee.EmployeeID == c.EmployeeID)
                        select c.StartDate).OrderByDescending(z => z);
```

or:

```
var SD = db.HolidayRequestForms
    .Where(c => c.Employee.Email == name && c.Employee.EmployeeID == c.EmployeeID)
    .OrderByDescending(z => z.StartDate)
    .Select(y => y.StartDate);
```

*You will also want to use `FirstOrDefault` rather than `LastOrDefault`.*