# How do I get the most recent entry from a table using LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a table of prices, which has a column for Date Updated. Every time there is a price change, a new entry is made to the table.

In order to return the most up to date price, I am trying to order by date, and then use .Last() to get the newest entry:

```
 var upgrades = from d in vf.tl_phn_devices
                       where d.available == true
                       select new
                       {
                           DeviceName = d.tl_phn_manufacturer.manufacturer + " " + d.model,
                           Price = (from p in vf.tl_phn_prices 
                                    where p.deviceID == d.deviceID
                                    orderby p.dateUpdated ascending
                                    select p.price).Last(),
                           URL = d.url,
                           ImageURL = d.image

                       };
```

However, when I run the above I get an error saying that .Last() is unsupported.
I have also tried .AsEnumberable().Last() but this didn't work either.

Elsewhere in the code I got round a similar issue by taking an extra step:

```
  var orders = (from o in vf.tl_phn_orders
                    where o.login == CurrentUserName
                    orderby o.date ascending
                    select new
                     {
                         Login = o.login,
                         Name = o.name,
                         Device = o.tl_phn_device.tl_phn_manufacturer.manufacturer + " " + o.tl_phn_device.model,
                         Price = o.tl_phn_price.price,
                         date = o.date

                     }).AsEnumerable();

        var order = orders.LastOrDefault();
```

But I want to do it all in one "hit" so I can return it in the first query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do `orderby descending` and then Select `First`.

`Last` and `LastOrDefault` are [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253529/last-and-lastordefault-not-supported) with Entity framework, since they can't get translated into underlying language (SQL for your case)

```
orderby p.dateUpdated descending
select p.price).First(),
```

You may also see: [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: The linked page doesn't have horizontal scroll bar or is it just my browser

Comment: @ElectricRouge, its an MSDN page and it doesn't require horizontal scrolling on my screen

Comment: @ElectricRouge, just tried on second screen , and yes you have to select and scroll to right , strange. **MSDN man!!**

Answer (score 2):

Use `First()` and change the order:

```
 var upgrades = from d in vf.tl_phn_devices
                where d.available
                select new
                {
                    DeviceName = d.tl_phn_manufacturer.manufacturer + " " + d.model,
                    Price = (from p in vf.tl_phn_prices 
                             where p.deviceID == d.deviceID
                             orderby p.dateUpdated descending
                             select p.price).First(),
                    URL = d.url,
                    ImageURL = d.image    
                };
```

The problem is that EntityFramework cannot generate the SQL for your query.

Your second query's use of `.Last()` works because you have loaded the entities into memory (with `.AsEnumerable()`) and are now using LINQ to Objects instead of LINQ to Entities.

You cannot do the same with the first query because of the nested queries.