# how can i select last row in a group

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem getting last row in a each group. I am using Linq query to retrieve the groups.
Here is my LINQ query.

```
return View(db.tblMsgs.OrderByDescending(a => a.Id)
    .GroupBy(a => new { a.Sender, a.Receiver }).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
    .Where(a => a.Receiver == username).ToList());
```

using `FirstOfDefault()` I am getting first row in a group.
Using `LastOrDefault()` I am getting run time exception.

Comment: what run time exception you are getting ?

Comment: Add schema and errors that u face

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Last and LastOrDefault not supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253529/last-and-lastordefault-not-supported)

Comment: when i am using lastordefault i am getting this error.

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'TicketGeneration.Models.tblMsg LastOrDefault[tblMsg](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TicketGeneration.Models.tblMsg])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what I run into too, in some time now.

After a little bit of research I found out that only way that works as it must  is to reverse the list that you want the get the last item of and get the first item.

The reason behind this is that SQL languages does not have a statement as `SELECT BOTTOM` but `SELECT TOP`. Hence our `LastOrDefault` query could not be translated into SQL.
 The possible way of doing so is to `OrderByDescending` method.

```
return View(db.tblMsgs.OrderByDescending(a => a.Id)
    .GroupBy(a => new { a.Sender, a.Receiver }).Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.SomeAttribute).FirstOrDefault())
    .Where(a => a.Receiver == username).ToList());
```

**Edit:**

Only thing you should be choosy about is the column to order by. It can be the id field if it is an auto incremented number value, or an add date of the row(better be generated by server or it can cause problems).

Comment: Glad that it's working. Nice to see by just sparing some time we can help each others over the world! I would be more glad if you could accept the answer too.