# Entity Framework LINQ for finding sub items from LastOrDefault parent

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have few related objects and relation is like

```
    public class Project
{
    public List<ProjectEdition> editions;
}

public class ProjectEdition
{
    public List<EditionItem> items;
}

public class EditionItem
{

}
```

I wanted to fetch the EditionItems from Last entries of ProjectEditions only for each Project

Example

Project#1 -> Edition#1 [contains few edition items ] , Edition#2 [contains few edition items]

Project#2 -> Edition#1 ,Edition#2 and Edition#3

My required output contains EditionItems from Edition#2 of Project#1 and Edition#3 of Project#2 only . I mean  EditionItems from latest edition of a Project or last edition of a Project only

To get this i tried this query

```
 List<EditionItem> master_list = context.Projects.Select(x => x.ProjectEditions.LastOrDefault())
                                      .SelectMany(x => x.EditionItems).ToList();
```

But its returns error at LatsOrDefault() section

An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '---------.Models.ProjectEdition LastOrDefault[ProjectEdition](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1

so how can i filter for last edition of a project and then get the list of EditionItems from it in a single LINQ call

Comment: sort in reverse order and get `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: As your exception says, `LastOrDefault()` is not supported by your provider. And if you think about it, when you work with SQL term of "last" does not make sense if no sort order is applied, as records can come from the server without particular order.

Comment: Then how can i achieve the same ? I am using SQL Server entity framework model

Comment: You must choose by which property in `ProjectEdition` you want to order the entities. Let's say there is a property `Id` in there, then you can use `List<EditionItem> master_list = context.Projects.Select(x => x.ProjectEditions.OrderByDescending(pe => pe.Id).FirstOrDefault()).SelectMany(x => x.EditionItems).ToList();`

Comment: @granit indeed, exactly that. You should make it as an answer.

Comment: @trailmax thanks for the suggestion, I did so.

Answer (score 4):

Granit got the answer right, so I won't repeat his code. I would like to add the reasons for this behaviour.

Entity Framework is magic (sometimes too much magic) but it yet translates your LINQ queries into SQL and there are limitations to that of what your underlying database can do (SQL Server in this case).

When you call `context.Projects.FirstOrDefault()` it is translated into something like `Select TOP 1 * from Projects`. Note the `TOP 1` part - this is SQL Server operator that limits number of rows returned. This is part of query optimisation in SQL Server. SQL Server does not have any operators that will give you `LAST 1` - because it needs to run the query, return all the results, take the last one and dump the rest - this is not very efficient, think of a table with a couple (bi)million records.

So you need to apply whatever required sort order to your query and limit number of rows you return. If you need last record from the query - apply reverse sort order. You do need to sort because [SQL Server does not guarantee order of records returned](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188385%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) if no `Order By` is applied to the query - this is due to the way the data is stored internally.

When you write LINQ queries with EF I do recommend keep an eye on what SQL is generated by your queries - sometimes you'll see how complex they come out and you can easily simplify the query. And sometimes with lazy-loading enabled you introduce N+1 problem with a stroke of a key (literally). I use [ExpressProfiler](http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/) to watch generated SQL, LinqPad can also show you the SQL queries and there are other tools.

Comment: Useful explaination!

Answer (score 2):

```
List<EditionItem> master_list = context.Projects
                                .Select(p => p.editions.LastOrDefault())
                                .SelectMany(pe => pe.items).ToList();
```

IF LastOrDefault not supported you can try using OrderByDescending

```
List<EditionItem> master_list = context.Projects
              .Select(p => p.editions.OrderByDescending(e => e.somefield).FirstOrDefault())
              .SelectMany(pe => pe.items).ToList();
```

Comment: can you try using OrderByDescending, p.editions.OrderByDescending().FirstOrDefault() ?

Comment: @JibinMathew, also check make sure your context.Projects return IEnumerable, so try using context.Projects.AsEnumerable().Select().

Comment: down voting with useful comments helps!

Comment: @MukeshModhvadiya it wasn't useful before you added the `order by` into the question - it was just the same as the OP had in the question. With the edit it is helpful indeed, down-vote removed.

Comment: @trailmax, thank you very much for explaination, I have executed it and posted working query! As soon as I noticed LastOrDefault not supported I added comment for Orderby, and updated answer later! thnx :)

Comment: @MukeshModhvadiya You might consider removing the `AsEnumerable` suggestions because it's a terrible idea to load the whole table in memory and then execute LINQ to Objects queries where things like lazy/eager loading has to be taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use method `LastOrDefault()` or `Last()` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253529/last-and-lastordefault-not-supported).

Insetad, you can use `OrderByDescending()` in conjunction with `FirstOrDefault()` but first you need to have a property in you `ProjectEdition` with which you want to order the entities. E.g. if `ProjectEdition` has a property `Id` (which there is a good chance it does), you can use the following LINQ query:

```
List<EditionItem> master_list = context.Projects.Select(
                  x => x.ProjectEditions
                      .OrderByDescending(pe => pe.Id)
                      .FirstOrDefault())
                      .SelectMany(x => x.EditionItems).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from p in context.project
from e in p.projectEdition.LastOrDefault()
select new EditionItem
{
    item1 = e.item1
}
```

Please try this