# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method using LastOrDefault

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Why I get the error below with this LINQ expression:

```
Models.Order last = context.Orders.LastOrDefault(o => o.customerID == customer.customerID);
```

And not with this:

```
Models.Order last = context.Orders.Where(o => o.customerID == customer.customerID).OrderByDescending(o => o.orderID).ToList()[0];
```

Error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
method 'Corporate.Models.Order LastOrDefault[Order](System.Linq.IQueryable`1
[Corporate.Models.Order], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2
[Corporate.Models.Order,System.Boolean]])' method, and this method cannot be
translated into a store expression.
```

Comment: Probably just because EF does not know how to transform `LastOrDefault` to valid SQL, while in the second example you tell it how it works.

Comment: @fubo I wanted to suggest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253529/last-and-lastordefault-not-supported, but I guess yours is also okay.